# "Error initializing Java Runtime Environment. You may need to reinstall Flash"

Tags: flash

I get this error starting up Flash Professional CS5 (on 32-bit XP). I don't even have to create/open a Flash file. I already reinstalled, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: thanks for posting, it applies to cs6 too!

Comment: @fermionoid - I don't have the problem in CS6, but then I have to say that I also switched from Windows XP to 7. Maybe that has something to do with it as well.

Comment: hmm really? I'm actually on windows 7-64bit...

Comment: @fermioniod - There seem to be several factors involved, so same OS version and same CS version don't guarantee anything. I posted this 2 and a half years ago and haven't found a definite solution, neither here, nor elsewhere on the 'Net. One often recommended solution is to reinstall JRE (didn't work for me). Adobe remains silent. :-(

Comment: what features will actually not work with that error? Just curious...

Comment: @fermionoid - None of ActionScript will work. Apparently the ActionScript interpreter is written in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this when I launched Flash CS5 and found that it was due to recent JAVA upgrade.  Fortunately, I backed up my HD files using Time Machine and went back and found an earlier preference file.  Here's what I did.

On the Mac I replaced the JAVA Preference version 13.6.0 with an earlier version of 13.5.0 located at:

- local_HD/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences

After replacing this file, the error message went away. I'm using a MacBookPro and OS 10.6.8.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, and thought: what if this EXE cannot reach the Java runtime environment because of a permission problem? And it is!

So, if you're running Windows 7 or Vista, make sure to open Flash by running it as an Administrator. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was **Software Restriction Policy** which I configured to block everything except application directories.

Adobe installs its JRE in ProgramData folder. So, I added a path rule for `C:\ProgramData\Adobe\CS5\jre` to my **Additional Rules**.

If you do not have Software Restriction Policy configured, then this solution does not apply to you.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue with flash professional cs5 on a mac (10.5.8). for me, it was caused by updating java, and changing the system's CurrentJDK symlink to 1.6. reverting the symlink to 1.5 made the issue go away. for those on a mac, here are the steps i followed in the terminal:

1)
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions

2) 
sudo ln -fhsv 1.5 CurrentJDK

(requires that you've unlocked root access for your mac)

for windows, you might also try this adobe knowledge-base article:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/405/kb405652.html

Comment: I would strongly recommend you do not do this. I did it and not only did it not work - but now I cannot download updates to my mac. Colin, do you know any way to revert to whatever the regular symlink was before running this command?

Comment: it's highly unlikely that changing a java symlink would disable all mac os updates. what evidence do you have to support your claim? the change worked for me, and i'm not sure you should downvote until you know for sure changing the symlink put your system in a crippled state. making a symlink change to the CurrentJDK affects program access to java, but is pretty trivial and non-destructive.  you can easily revert with: sudo ln -fhsv 1.6 CurrentJDK. can you post an ls -las of your /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions directory?